# bash does not parse color characters in terminal

Tags: bash, terminal

I am connecting through ssh to an embedded linux to do some stuff. In outut of commands like `journalctl` and `systemctl` I see these random characters which look like color directives. They really ruining the look and feel of the logs and I just dont want to see them. Is there anyway I can get rid of it? or somehow make it work?

```
Mar 29 08:27:02 MyHost kernel: EXT4-fs (sda6): mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem
Mar 29 08:27:02 MyHost udisksd[2051]: [[0;1;39m[[0;1;31m[[0;1;39mMounted /dev/sda6 at /run/media/root/TYPE-EXT3 on behalf of uid 0[[0m
```

$SHELL is set to `/bin/bash`

Comment: The terminal (emulator) would interpret the colors, not bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the environment variable `$SYSTEMD_COLORS` to false.

From the `systemctl` man page:

> $SYSTEMD_COLORS
> Takes a boolean argument. When true, systemd and related
> utilities will use colors in their output, otherwise the
> output will be monochrome.

Comment: so that will b `$ export  SYSTEMD_COLORS=falsee`? right?

Comment: Yes, if you spell 'false' correctly.